# Problem with IE8 and printing a Dojo chart

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-8, charts, dojo

I have a Dojo Chart that I want to print using File - Print in IE8, but it comes out blank both on the printer and in Print Preview.  If I use IE7 or change IE8's Document Mode to IE7 Standards it prints out just fine. Does any one know what the difference is or how to work around it ?

Comment: Just carry on using IE7?